# Forward Collapse in Excel Row using Apache POI

Tags: excel, apache-poi, forward

My requirement is exactly similar to below given sample code except for the expansion is reverse here i.e on expanding (+) 7th row it shows from 4th row.

http://www.mysamplecode.com/2011/10/apache-poi-excel-row-group-collapse.html

My requirement is just opposite expansion sign(+) to be 4th row and on expand show rows till 7th.

Is there any way we can achieve this. I tried all available methods ..it appears to be I got exhausted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
sheet1.setRowSumsBelow(false);
```

This excel attribute is set for the whole sheet (applies to all groups of rows inside the sheet).